# Why does the review log for some questions not show who is voting to close it?

Tags: discussion

I have just noticed that the review log for ["Adam and Eve and the 10 Commandments"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28470/adam-and-eve-and-the-10-commandments) does not show who is voting to close it. Is this normal?

The same is true for ["Nudity in the bible - Genesis 2 and 3"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28460/nudity-in-the-bible-genesis-2-and-3). There is 1 vote in the review log to leave it open, but there is a vote-to-close showing on the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the event that a question is actually closed, who voted for that will become public record. However, at the stage where it is still open there is nothing that should be *done* based on that information. Showing it would just cause more drama than necessary and bias other voters, whether for or against based on the names they recognize voting. Like it or not, seeing a name you trust or agree with would tend to garner your vote and names you don't trust or tend to agree with would tend to garner no action — both apart from the merits of the post.

**VTC should be placed based on the merits of the question and each reviewer should analyze it themselves.** In the event there is some specific case to be made, voters can make it in comments. Notably VTC as duplicate outs the first voter because it auto generates a comment. In these cases there is additional material to be reviewed beyond just the question when considering your vote.

Comment: Thanks, Caleb. I understand.

Answer (score 2):

The review log only shows close votes that arise as actions of the review. If you vote to close it through viewing the question normally then your vote is hidden until the question is closed and the names of all the close voters are shown.

Comment: Thanks, curiousdannii. I understand.